# Need delay before CreateFile( )?

Tags: c, winapi, file-io, delay

I have one question about the use of [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

My code sequence is as follows:

```
CreateFile to get handle A
.....
Close handle A
GetDiskFreeSpace  // if handle A is not closed, this API fails...
.....         
CreateFile to get handle B  // for File writing Ex. f:\test.dat
WriteFile via handle B      // write file
Close handle B                        
.....
CreateFile to get handle C  // where handle C and A points to the same target !
```

My discovery is: if no delay before *`"CreateFile to get handle C"`* then I got the error message **"Error: 5 Access denied"**

But if I add 1s delay(Ex. Sleep(1000)) before it then everything is ok and handle C is valid one !

Could anyone give me some comments ?

@ Platform: VS2008, Win7, testing drive is USB flash pen drive

Comment: Sounds like your pen-drive is buggy (or the drivers for it).

Comment: I forgot to say that handle A,B and C share the same handle variable. And I found if `allocating another handle variable for B`, then this delay is not necessary and everything is ok ! (I still did not know the reason why)

Comment: That STILL sounds like a bad driver type problem - the driver is holding on to things after it should have been released.

Comment: This error occurs again in some case >_<   Which driver can I check ?

Comment: Most common cause for this is the virus scanner being rubbish. Try disabling it and then testing again.

Comment: Someone else with similar problem, no definitive resolution: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/closehandle-file-buffering-help-28037352.html

Comment: Hi all, after disabling the virus scanner this error is absent. I will try more PCs later. Thanks !